# AVAudio Won't Stop after Presenting Modal View

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer, viewdidappear, modal-view

I have an application that displays movies. The first screen shows buttons that present different modal views. Inside those modal views are buttons that play videos.

I want the main menu to play music (easy enough), but I want it to persist through the second modal view but stop when the video starts playing.

I've trying [audioPlayer stop] when the buttons for the movies are pressed, but the music keeps playing.

I have tried stopping and playing the audio in viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear. That has made the audio restart upon presenting the second view and not playing during the video.

I hope this makes sense, I really just need an idea of how to get the audio to play all of the time (throughout two or three modal views) except for during movie playback.

**Here's my `vewDidAppear` method:**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   NSString *musicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Intro Music" ofType:@"mp3"]; 
   if(musicPath) {
     NSURL *musicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicPath];
     audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicURL error:nil];
     [musicURL release]; 
   }
   if(!audioPlayer.playing) {
     [audioPlayer play]
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to stay on top of your questions and select the correct answer.

Comment: Would you please post some code? I think it might where are you telling the audio player to stop? Is it in the same class that created it?

Comment: Can I see your header file too, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal view controller is trying to stop an `audioPlayer` which does not exists inside of it. The `mainMenueViewController` has the `audioPlayer`, so *it* has to be the one to tell the audio player to stop.

You can use NSNotifications for this. Each [NSNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNotification) is sent through the singleton [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Here are the basic steps for your situation:

1. Your main menu registers for notifications when it is ready.
2. Your main menu has methods to call when the notifications fire.
3. Your submenu fires a method when it needs to turn off the audio.
4. Your main menu unregisters when it's ready to close.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yikes, I'm really sorry about the formatting. I'm not quite sure how to fix that.

Comment: @Brett - No worries. Why don't you edit your question to add the code? Most folks do when they need to add code or clarify. Comments aren't ideal for code. To get that formatting though, use ` instead of '.

Comment: I've added that code for you @Brett. Actuially, I'm curious to see what your view lifecycle methods look like.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not really sure how to answer that question. I have a view controller that presents modal views on top of the main menu when buttons are pressed. The videos are presented as a modal view as well. It's like a chain of modal views. Does that answer the question?

Comment: View lifecycle methods are viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewWillDisappear, viewWillUnload etc.

Comment: I haven't implemented those to do anything. I tried putting [audioPlayer stop] in viewDidDisappear, but it just restarted the song once the next menu was shown.

Comment: Ah, ok. Have you tried putting `@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer audioPlayer;` in your header file? I think that it's a referencing issue, but I can only guess unless I see more code.

Comment: I did try that earlier when I was trying to figure it out. I just put it back in and I'm getting the same behavior. I like how it plays through the modal views, I just want it to stop when I push the buttons to play the videos. I have [audioPlayer stop] in the IBAction methods for the buttons that play the movies. It seems like it's just being ignored.

Comment: Use NSLog to make sure those methods are being called. If they are, I have one other possible idea.

Comment: The methods that play the movie or the lifecycle methods?

Comment: The methods that play the movie.

Comment: Well they are being called since the movies play. I put a breakpoint on the [audioPlayer stop] line and it is executed it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. Your modal view doesn't contain an audioPlayer. You should send a notification to the menu view using NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: Even though I am calling [self presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES]? I think I am confused on where to send the notifications since all of the IBAction methods are in the same class.

Comment: @Brett - Please post your custom methods and what classes they're in. I would like to see the main menu view controller and the modal view. (By the way, I'm on my computer now - I was on my iPhone before. Wanna hop over to the MSO Tavern? http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general )